# Is a Jewish med student allowed to use body parts donated to science?

Tags: halacha, death, medicine, science, college-university-school

Would you be required to refuse to work on bodies donated to science for educational purposes?

Comment: I know this answer is no but I don't have a source at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our views towards *donating* one's body for medical studies aren't so simple.

But if the body is already here, and the medical student is expected to dissect a cadaver as part of their medical education (let's assume the student is not a kohen), Rabbi Joseph Soloveichik is quoted as saying that it is wholly appropriate -- "would *you* go to a doctor who's never taken apart a body before?" (As heard from his student and biographer, Rabbi Aaron Rakeffet-Rothkoff, on one of his many mp3 lectures.)

Comment: Only heard on one of them? :)

Comment: @IsaacMoses, well I only listen to one at a time ...